# Using VectorAssembler in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I got the following dataframe (it is assumed that it is already a dataframe):

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2, 10), (3, 4, 11), (5, 6, 12)))
           .toDF("a", "b", "c")
```

and I want to combine the columns(not all) to one column and make it an rdd of Array[Double]. I am doing the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
val colSelected = List("a","b")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(colSelected.toArray)
    .setOutputCol("features")
val output = assembler.transform(df).select("features").rdd
```

Till here it is ok. Now the output is a dataframe of the format `RDD[spark.sql.Row]`. I am unable to transform this to a format of `RDD[Array[Double]]`. Any way?

I have tried something like the following but with no success:

```scala
output.map { case Row(a: Vector[Double]) => a.getAs[Array[Double]]("features")}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution (this assumes Spark 2.0+, in 1.x use `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector`):

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

output.map(_.getAs[Vector]("features").toArray)
```

- `ml` / `mllib` `Vector` created by `VectorAssembler` is not the same as `scala.collection.Vector`.
- `Row.getAs` should be used with expected type. It doesn't perform any type conversions and `o.a.s.ml(lib).linalg.Vector` is not an `Array[Double]`.